# Changing the textContentType for a UITextField programmatically doesn't update keyboard autofill

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield

I am setting the `.textContentType` on a `UITextField` and then changing it programmatically (as I am reusing a `UITextField`). I'm also not dismissing the keyboard after I change it.

The keyboard does not update to show autofill options for the new `.textContentType`. I've also confirmed in the debugger that the `UITextField` has its `.textContentType` updated:

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.becomesFirstResponder() // show the keyboard
textField.textContentType = .email
textField.textContentType = .familyName // Doesn't update keyboard autofill
```

The above example is a simplification of my actual code, but should reproduce the problem. You might say, why don't I create a new UITextField or dismiss the keyboard - the view I'm creating is similar to the iMessage flow where one text field is reused for different messages, so reuse it pretty important.

EDIT:
When you leave the application and come back, the keyboard will have the updated autofill.

Answer (score 1):

The only was I was able to solve this was by creating a second `UITextField` with a different `textContentType` and switching them out for each other.